# How to return index of Object array used by JOptionPane for use in a switch statement?

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

I am experimenting with variations on the dialog box tutorial on Oracle. I felt that the number of options I offered resulted in too many buttons so I converted from OptionDialog to InputDialog and used an Object array. Now, however, my switch statement (in replyMessage) doesn't work because of the change in data type. How do I get the index in the Object array corresponding to the user's selection?

```
Object answer;        
    int ansInt;//the user'a answer stored as an int

    Object[] options = {"Yes, please",
            "No, thanks",
            "No eggs, no ham!",
            "Something else",
            "Nothing really"
        };//end options
    answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like some green eggs to go with that ham?",
        "A Silly Question",
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        null,
        options,
        options[2]);

    ansInt = ;//supposed to be the index of user's seleection   

    replyMessage(ansInt);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`showInputDialog` will return the string that the user entered, which is one of the strings in the `options` array. The shortest way to know which index was selected is to loop on the `options` array and find equality:

```
for(i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  if(options[i].equals(answer) {
    ansInt = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

Another possibility is to have a map of key/values:

```
Map<String, Integer> optionsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
options = optionsMap.keySet().toArray();
... Call the dialog ...
ansInt = optionsMap.get(answer);
```

The first option is good if the number of options is low. If you have many options, the second solution will perform a lot better. For even better performance, you can cache the`optionsMap` and `options` array.