# How to get int value of selected item from JOptionPane?

Tags: java, combobox, joptionpane

Is there a way to get the selected index of the selected item when using JOptionPane with a combobox?

In the below code, I can get the Selected Value, but I need the selected index.

```
String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Select Mechanic: ",
"Select Mechanic", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, mechanics, mechanics[0]);
```

Is it possible to get the selected index with JOptionPane?

Comment: After a quick Google search I came across this StackOverFLow thread. I hope that it helps you with what you require. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489845/how-to-return-index-of-object-array-used-by-joptionpane-for-use-in-a-switch-stat

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy. Just do not cast your result to a String:

```
int input = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Select Mechanic: ",
"Select Mechanic", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, mechanics, mechanics[0]);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work as the return type is 'object'

Comment: @forseth31 ah I see try showOptionDialog instead of showInputDialog

Comment: the showOptionDialog returns the selected index, but it displays the options as buttons instead of a combobox